# Python newline constant like C++ std::endl

Tags: python, newline, string-formatting

I am formatting a string (in magic method `__str__`) and I don't want to use a raw `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`.

Does python have a cross-platform newline identifier like [`std::endl`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/) in C++?

I tried to Google it, but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about using `os.linesep`? It contains the appropriate line separator for your OS:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.linesep
'\n'
>>> print "line one" + os.linesep + "line two"
line one
line two
```

Answer (score 8):

No. Use `\n`. And in C++, `std::endl` is nothing other than `"\n" << std::flush`, and it is *not* more cross-platform, whatever that would mean. It's only slower, as it forces flushing.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong with using `\n` - why don't you want to use it? The cross-platform problem is only relevant when writing to files, and the `file`-object takes care of that for you.